# Apex RestService parameter not passing over

Tags: rest-service

I have a Apex RestService that looks like:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/feed/*')
global with sharing class RestFeedInbound 
{
    @HttpGet 
    global static FeedItem newFeedEntry()
    {
        FeedItem newChatterFeedItem = new FeedItem(
        Title=RestContext.request.params.get('title'),
        Body=RestContext.request.params.get('body'),
        ParentId=UserInfo.getUserId());

        insert newChatterFeedItem;

        FeedItem returnFeedItem = [Select Title, Body from FeedItem where Id=:newChatterFeedItem.Id];
        return returnFeedItem ;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class RestFeedInboundTest {

    @isTest static void testRestFeedInbound() {

        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        req.requestURI = 'https://na10.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/feed?title=CloudSoleChatterTitle&body=CloudSoleInboundApexChatterMessage';  
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';

        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;

        FeedItem restFeed = RestFeedInbound.newFeedEntry();

        System.assertEquals('CloudSoleChatterTitle', res.getBody());
        System.assertEquals('CloudSoleInboundApexChatterMessage', res.Body);
    }
}
```

Get this message:

REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Body]: [Body]

Looks like body is not passed over. Any suggestions why?

Comment: If you are not passing in parameters how do you write tests for your Apex rest endpoints? Can you inject a RestContext object during in your test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:
`Body=RestContext.request.params.get('body')`

You don't get the body of your restrequest from the rest parameters, you get it from the actual request body, which returns a blob.

Try changing your code to:

`Body = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString()`